# filter a list of strings according to user input excluding multiple blank spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to filter a list of strings according to user input using a regex and excluding multiple blank spaces:

### What I have

```js
const suggestions = ['las vegas', 'last resort', 'other last'];
const searchTerm = 'Las';

const regex = RegExp(searchTerm.trim(), 'i');
const filtered = suggestions.filter((suggestion) =>
  regex.test(suggestion),
);
```

### What I want

although the above approach works, the error I have encountered is that if I type multiple blank spaces I get back all items in the list, what I would expect is that if there are multiple blanks, it will not return anything i.e. no match found.

you can test the above behavior by replacing:

`const searchTerm = 'Las'` => `const searchTerm = '   ';`

### EDIT 1

I need to use a regex(RegExp) for two reasons:

- I need to run additional capturing group process
- The input is entered by the user(is a dynamic input)

Comment: `trim()` removes all the blanks at the beginning and end. If the search term is just blanks, it removes them all, and you just have an empty string. This matches everything.

Comment: The simplest solution is to just check if `searchTerm.trim()` is empty.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a regex? Users don't generally know that certain characters have special meaning, and you're not escaping those characters. You could just use `suggestion.includes(searchTerm)`

Comment: @Barmar
I need to use a regex(RegExp) for two reasons:
1. I need to run additional capturing group process
2. The input is entered by the user(is a dynamic input)

Comment: @CristianFlórez No, you don't understand. You don''t want to use regex for dynamic input. Regex is for static input only

Comment: @mousetail according the mozilla doc, u need to use `RegExp` for dynamic inputs:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#building_a_regular_expression_from_dynamic_inputs, I also need to run some capturing group process. How would you capture substrings with a dynamic input without regex?

Comment: @CristianFlórez No, you misunderstood that article. Yes RegExp can be used to excape dynamic inputs inside a normal regular expression but you don't want to use regular expressions at all

Comment: @mousetail could you create an answer with the necessary details, so I can better understand why not to use regex and what other solution I could use.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a brute force approach, but could work depending on your other requirements; what about you use helper variables to simply ignore *all* whitespace and check if there is any relevant input as kind of a guard clause?

```js
const suggestions = ['las vegas', 'last resort', 'other last'];

const p = document.querySelector("p")
const btn = document.querySelector("button")
const input = document.querySelector("input")

btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const searchTermRaw = input.value
  const searchTerm = searchTermRaw.replace(/\s/g, "")

  if (searchTerm) {
    const regex = RegExp(searchTerm, 'i')

    const filtered = suggestions.filter(s =>
      regex.test(s.replace(/\s/g, ""))
    );
    p.innerText = filtered.join()
  } else {
    p.innerText = "No results :("
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
<button>Search</button>
<p></p>
```